# How made this become no repeatation?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to change this to unique number and no repeat...how? 
Please give me some suggestions to change this code problems...
I need 20 unique numbers and I need to made them become unique and no repeat at the same line...
This is the question that my teacher gave me:

```
import java.lang.*; 
// import java.util.Random;

class UniqueRandomIntArray {

//   static Random rnGen = new Random();

   private static void uriArray(int[] rray) {
      int low = 0;
      int high = 50;

      int rn;
      int haveit = 0;
      int i = 0; 
      int j;

      while((haveit == 0) && i < rray.length) {  
         rn = randNum(low, high);

         for(j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if(rn == rray[j]) {
               haveit = j;
               j = i;
               }
            }

         if(haveit != 0) {
            System.out.println("a[" + haveit + "] is " + rn + " already");
            haveit = 0;
            }
         else {
            System.out.println("a[" + i + "] is " + rn);
            rray[i] = rn;
            i++;
            }

         }   // end while
      }      // end uriArray


   private static int randNum(int min, int max) {
      int range = (max - min) + 1;
//      int randnum = rnGen.nextInt(range) + min;
      int randnum = (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
      return randnum;
      }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] arra = new int[20];
      uriArray(arra);
      for(int i=0; i<arra.length; i++)  {
         System.out.print(" | " + arra[i]);
         }
      System.out.println(" | ");
      }

   } //class ends
```

Comment: Please review the answers below and mark one correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use `Collections.shuffle()`

```
    //create list of 50 integers in order 0..49
    List<Integer> intlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int n=0; n<50; n++) intlist.add(n);

    //randomize the order
    Collections.shuffle(intlist);

    //print the list
    for (int n : intlist) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
```

Comment: Where should I put this in?

Answer (score 1):

Math.Radnom() does not guarantee uniqueness.

You could do two things, on top of my mind:

Suggestion one:

- Generate 20 different intervals
- take one random number from each interval
- Since the intervals do not overlap, your numbers are random and unique
- use Collections.shuffle against collection with your numbers

Suggestion two:

- iterate over some interval
- define probability of acceptance
- invoke Math.random() and see if your got value higher or equal to this probability
- if yes, add number to array, else skip
- stop when you have 20 numbers
- use Collections.shuffle against collection with your numbers

Answer (score 0):

A sleaker solution to your problem is to use a `Set` to store the random numbers, and to keep adding new random numbers to this set in the range [0,50] until you have 20 of them:

```
public static int[] getRandNums() {
    Set<Integer> randNums = new HashSet<Integer>();

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    do {
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(50);  // generate random number between
        randNums.add(randomInt);                      // 0 and 50

        if (randNums.size() == 20) break;             // exit the loop at 20 numbers
    } while(true);

    Integer[] resultInt = randNums.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    int[] result = new int[resultInt.length];
    for (int ctr=0; ctr < resultInt.length; ++ctr) {
        result[ctr] = resultInt[ctr].intValue();
    }

    return result;                                    // return numbers as an array
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = getRandNums();
    for (int i=0; i< array.length; ++i) {
       System.out.print(" | " + arra[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(" | ");
}
```

I am choosing to not strictly stick to your original code because it is messy.

Comment: So I need to set the new array just like yours?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is nearly working, but you can have a duplicate with the first value in your array.

Your problem is with the fact that you use `0` for `haveit` to check if you don't have that number, so, if you already have that number at index `0`, you will consider that you don't have it. You can use `-1` instead of `0`:

- change

  ```
  int haveit = 0;
  ```

  to

  ```
  int haveit = -1;
  ```
- change

  ```
  while ((haveit == 0) && i < rray.length) {
  ```

  to

  ```
  while ((haveit == -1) && i < rray.length) {
  ```
- change

  ```
  if(haveit != 0) {
      System.out.println("a[" + haveit + "] is " + rn + " already");
      haveit = 0;
  }
  ```

  to

  ```
  if(haveit != -1) {
      System.out.println("a[" + haveit + "] is " + rn + " already");
      haveit = -1;
  }
  ```

Comment: How to do the sorting part for the duplicate numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Create a List containing each of the candidate numbers. Use [Collections.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) to shuffle it. Copy the first 20 elements to the result array.

Answer (score 0):

Have a default `haveit` of `-1` instead of `0`. Because 0 is a possible valid value of `haveit`.